# Statistical analysis of bud burst - handling a whole group of 0s with a mean of 0?

Tags: confidence-interval, t-test, binary-data, minitab

I have two treatments A and B which have been applied to tree buds to see if they will burst in a set time period. The outcome is binary - burst or not burst (yes or no, 1 or 0). There are an uneven number of buds in each group. In group A there were 100 buds and 38 burst. In group B there were 79 buds and 0 burst. I have been advised to do a 2 sample T test using minitab but I get an error message as all values in group B are 0 - the test simply wont run. What test can I do that will measure the validity of these stats?
The null hypothesis is that there will be no difference in the proportion of bud burst between the two treatments.

Comment: you should be doing a proportion test.

Comment: The normal distribution cannot apply in this case so the t test is not appropriate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per AdamO's comment I have now done a proportion test. For minitab (18.0) users this is under stat > basic statistics > 2 proportions, it includes a Fisher's exact test. For my case the null hypothesis was rejected p<0.00.